# Probability to win between 7 and 10 games of the next 15 games

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

The probability that the Mets win is .8.  What is the probability they win between 7 and 10 games of the next 15 games?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the binomial distribution?

Comment: Must be a different Mets than the New York baseball team. Let $X$ be the number of games they win. We want $\Pr(X=7)+\Pr(X=8)+\Pr(X=9)+\Pr(X=10)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Look at the binomial distribution.

Answer (score -2):

look at the table of binomial probabilities.
N=15
P(710)= .003+.014+.043+.103=.163